# Calculating support of an amount based on a threshold in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Lets say I have a `data.table` which looks like this

```
    customer TranAmount
 1:   146506    1290.49
 2:   146506    2699.00
 3:   146506    2720.00
 4:   146506    2700.00
 5:   146506       6.35
 6:   146506    2700.00
 7:   146506    2705.00
 8:   146506    2691.00
 9:   146506     500.00
10:   146506     500.95
11:   146506      52.00
```

Now I want to calculate `support` of each amount, by `support` I mean if I pick 
a transaction and there are transactions which is within the threshold of that transaction, then `support` of that transaction is equal to the number of transaction within that limit.

For example in the above data, for `TranAmount` 2700.00, if we consider a threshold of 1% (above 2700.00 or below 2700.00) then there are 6 transactions within that range, so `support` for  TranAmount `2700.00` is 6

I have written this function which does that but its slow and certainly not in `data.table` way but it does the job, I am sure there are better ways to achieve this, but I cant think of any.

```
get_support <- function(dt,val_tolerance=0.01) {
    support_dt <- dt[,.(customer,TranAmount)][order(TranAmount)]
    support_dt[,support:= 0]

    for(i in 1:nrow(support_dt)) {
      start <- support_dt[i,TranAmount]
      current_support <- support_dt[i,support]
      amount_limit <- c((start - start*val_tolerance),(start + start*val_tolerance))
      for (j in 1:nrow(support_dt)){
        amount <- support_dt[j,TranAmount]
        if(between(amount,amount_limit[1],amount_limit[2]) ==TRUE ){
          current_support <- current_support+1
        }else{
          current_support <- current_support
        }
      }
      #print(current_support)
      support_dt[i,support:=current_support]
    } 
    print(support_dt)
}
```

Please suggest better way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With version 1.9.7 or later, use non-equi joins:

```
vals = c(2700, 500)

DT[.(dn = vals*0.99, up = vals*1.01), on=.(TranAmount >= dn, TranAmount <= up), 
  .N
, by=.EACHI]

#    TranAmount TranAmount N
# 1:       2673       2727 6
# 2:        495        505 2
```

The column names in the result aren't very intuitive, but those might change.

Currently (Aug 2016), you'll need to [install the devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) for this.

Answer (score 2):

I got warnings but apparently the logic was sound:

```
 dt[ , support := ave(TranAmount, TranAmount,
                           FUN= function(x) sum(abs(x -dt$TranAmount) < 0.01*x) ) ]
 #---------------------------------
Warning messages:
1: In x - dt$TranAmount :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In abs(x - dt$TranAmount) < 0.01 * x :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> dt
    customer TranAmount support
 1:   146506    1290.49       1
 2:   146506    2699.00       6
 3:   146506    2720.00       5
 4:   146506    2700.00       6
 5:   146506       6.35       1
 6:   146506    2700.00       6
 7:   146506    2705.00       6
 8:   146506    2691.00       5
 9:   146506     500.00       2
10:   146506     500.95       2
11:   146506      52.00       1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hacky `data.table` solution that works (there is likely a cleaner way though)

```
tvals <- df$TranAmount
pct   <- 0.01

dfDT[, id := .I][,support := sum( TranAmount*(1-pct) <= tvals & tvals <= TranAmount*(1+pct) ), by = list(id)][,id:=NULL]
```

**EDIT**: an alternate `data.table` approach

```
dfDT[, support := sum( TranAmount*(1-pct) <= tvals & tvals <= TranAmount*(1+pct) ), by = rownames(dfDT)]
```

and here is a `dplyr` solution

```
df %>%
    group_by(rn=row_number()) %>%
    mutate(support = sum( TranAmount*(1-pct) <= tvals & tvals <= TranAmount*(1+pct) ) ) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-rn)

##    customer TranAmount support
##       <int>      <dbl>   <int>
## 1    146506    1290.49       1
## 2    146506    2699.00       6
## 3    146506    2720.00       5
## 4    146506    2700.00       6
## 5    146506       6.35       1
## 6    146506    2700.00       6
## 7    146506    2705.00       6
## 8    146506    2691.00       5
## 9    146506     500.00       2
## 10   146506     500.95       2
## 11   146506      52.00       1
```

Note, `df` (`data.frame`) and `dfDT` (`data.table`) contain the same data.

Comment: thats really hacky :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively simple data.table way

```
x[, support := x[abs(TranAmount- .SD[,TranAmount]) < 0.01*.SD[,TranAmount] , .N], 
    by=1:NROW(x)]

#    customer  TranAmount support
# 1:   146506 1290.49       1
# 2:   146506 2699.00       6
# 3:   146506 2720.00       5
# 4:   146506 2700.00       6
# 5:   146506    6.35       1
# 6:   146506 2700.00       6
# 7:   146506 2705.00       6
# 8:   146506 2691.00       5
# 9:   146506  500.00       2
#10:   146506  500.95       2
#11:   146506   52.00       1
```

The data:

```
x = data.table(customer=rep(146506,11), 
               TranAmount=c(1290.49, 2699.00, 2720.00, 2700.00, 6.35, 2700.00,
                            2705.00, 2691.00, 500.00, 500.95, 52.00))
```